# Google Translate Widget Select Language Menu Disappears When Attempting to Select a Language on iOS

Tags: android, ios, widget, google-translate

I have been having an issue when trying to select a language from the Google Translate Widget "Select Language" Menu on iOS Devices.  I can get the dropdown to show up without issue, but when I attempt to select a language the entire select language menu disappears.  I have tried this on Android Devices and this issue does not occur.  I have searched the forums and found one similar post in which the answer states that this is an issue attributed to Flash.  However, I have found a website that this issue does not occur on iOS devices so I know this flash explanation is not the case.

Any insight would help--the site I saw it was working on my iOS Device was http://www.akaiprompc.com.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Hammer.js and the iframe layout option of the Google Translate Widget do not play nice.  Please check out this related post:

[Why are touch event listeners seemingly preventing the selection of google translate languages on the iphone or ipad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197110/why-are-touch-event-listeners-seemingly-preventing-the-selection-of-google-trans)