# Cannot select language on Google Translator plugin on mobile

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, google-api, google-translate

Just implemented Google Translate widget to my website and it works perfect on Desktop, but on Mobile (e.g. iPhone) I can tap on the widget block, the drop down appears with the language list and then I am not able to select any of the languages, tapping it simply nothing happens. Can't really post any js, don't know what could be the problem. Was hoping maybe someone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same issue and this seems to be a bug - as outlined here:

[Why are touch event listeners seemingly preventing the selection of google translate languages on the iphone or ipad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197110/why-are-touch-event-listeners-seemingly-preventing-the-selection-of-google-trans)

The short answer is to replace the Simple Layout with Horizontal or Vertical so it won't render in an iframe.